# Calling a method with this pointer from an inherited class becomes const

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction

```
class A { }
class B : public A { 
    doSomething {
        C * c = new C(this);
    }
}
class C
{
    C(A* copy);
}
```

In the following example I get the following error:

> error: no matching function for call
>   to `C::C(B* const)'

I wan't to get the A pointer in the this call but for some reason I can't get this through. Probably some silly typo but as it's Rhapsody generated I don't really feel I have the control over why I get this issue when compiling.

Trying to add another headerfile. It wont compile as it's so many files that needs to be included but this is the actual code (changed class names) that is executed and the underlying classes is working.

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

//## auto_generated
#include <oxf/oxf.h>
//## auto_generated
#include "TestSequencePkg.h"
//## auto_generated
#include <oxf/omreactive.h>
//## auto_generated
#include <oxf/state.h>
//## auto_generated
#include <oxf/event.h>
//## class A
#include "D.h"
//## dependency F
#include "F.h"
//## class A
#include "C.h"
//## dependency G
#include "G.h"
//## class A
#include "B.h"
//## class A
#include "E.h"
//## operation A(TestContextC *)
class TestContextC;

//## package TestSequencePkg

//## class A
class A : public OMReactive, public B, public C, public D, public E {
    ////    Constructors and destructors    ////

public :

    //## operation A(TestContextC *)
    A(TestContextC * context, IOxfActive* theActiveContext = 0);

    //## auto_generated
    A(IOxfActive* theActiveContext = 0);

    //## operation ~A()
    ~A();

    ////    Operations    ////

    //## operation handleInMessage(AFBaseMsgC *)
    virtual ACE_UINT32 handleInMessage(AFBaseMsgC * msg);

    //## operation init()
    virtual void init();

    ////    Additional operations    ////

    //## auto_generated
    virtual bool startBehavior();

protected :

    //## auto_generated
    void initStatechart();

    ////    Framework operations    ////

public :

    // rootState:
    //## statechart_method
    inline bool rootState_IN() const;

    //## statechart_method
    inline bool rootState_isCompleted();

    //## statechart_method
    virtual void rootState_entDef();

    //## statechart_method
    void rootState_exit();

    //## statechart_method
    virtual IOxfReactive::TakeEventStatus rootState_processEvent();

    // UpdateData:
    //## statechart_method
    inline bool UpdateData_IN() const;

    // terminationstate_4:
    //## statechart_method
    inline bool terminationstate_4_IN() const;

    // CalculateFiringData:
    //## statechart_method
    inline bool CalculateFiringData_IN() const;

    // BookShell:
    //## statechart_method
    inline bool BookShell_IN() const;

    ////    Framework    ////

protected :

//#[ ignore
    enum TestSequenceBallisticCalcC_Enum {
        OMNonState = 0,
        UpdateData = 1,
        terminationstate_4 = 2,
        CalculateFiringData = 3,
        BookShell = 4
    };

    int rootState_subState;

    int rootState_active;
//#]
};

inline bool A::rootState_IN() const {
    return true;
}

inline bool A::rootState_isCompleted() {
    return ( IS_IN(terminationstate_4) );
}

inline bool A::UpdateData_IN() const {
    return rootState_subState == UpdateData;
}

inline bool A::terminationstate_4_IN() const {
    return rootState_subState == terminationstate_4;
}

inline bool A::CalculateFiringData_IN() const {
    return rootState_subState == CalculateFiringData;
}

inline bool A::BookShell_IN() const {
    return rootState_subState == BookShell;
}

#endif
```

and here is the cpp file.

```
//## auto_generated
#include <oxf/omthread.h>
//## auto_generated
#include "A.h"
//## operation handleInMessage(AFBaseMsgC *)
#include "AFBaseMsgC.h"
//## event evTestSuccess()
#include "TestBasePkg.h"
//## operation A(TestContextC *)
#include "TestContextC.h"
//## package TestSequencePkg

//## class A
A::A(TestContextC * context, IOxfActive* theActiveContext) : B(context) {
    setActiveContext(theActiveContext, false);
    initStatechart();
    //#[ operation A(TestContextC *)
    //#]
}

A::A(IOxfActive* theActiveContext) {
    setActiveContext(theActiveContext, false);
    initStatechart();
}

A::~A() {
    //#[ operation ~A()
    //#]
}

ACE_UINT32 A::handleInMessage(AFBaseMsgC * msg) {
    //#[ operation handleInMessage(AFBaseMsgC *)
    return getState();
    //#]
}

void A::init() {
    //#[ operation init()
    startBehavior();
    //#]
}

bool A::startBehavior() {
    bool done = false;
    done = OMReactive::startBehavior();
    return done;
}

void A::initStatechart() {
    rootState_subState = OMNonState;
    rootState_active = OMNonState;
}

void A::rootState_entDef() {
    {
        rootState_subState = BookShell;
        rootState_active = BookShell;
        //#[ state ROOT.BookShell.(Entry) 
        registerProcedure(new F(this, this, this));
        //#]
    }
}

void A::rootState_exit() {
    switch (rootState_subState) {
        case UpdateData:
        {
            popNullTransition();
            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
    rootState_subState = OMNonState;

}

IOxfReactive::TakeEventStatus A::rootState_processEvent() {
    IOxfReactive::TakeEventStatus res = eventNotConsumed;
    switch (rootState_active) {
        case BookShell:
        {
            if(IS_EVENT_TYPE_OF(evTestSuccess_TestBasePkg_id))
                {
                    rootState_subState = CalculateFiringData;
                    rootState_active = CalculateFiringData;
                    //#[ state ROOT.CalculateFiringData.(Entry) 
                    registerProcedure(new G(this, this, this, this));
                    //#]
                    res = eventConsumed;
                }
            else if(IS_EVENT_TYPE_OF(evTestFailure_TestBasePkg_id))
                {
                    //#[ transition 4 
                    setState(ABORTED);
                    //#]
                    rootState_subState = terminationstate_4;
                    rootState_active = terminationstate_4;
                    res = eventConsumed;
                }

            break;
        }
        case CalculateFiringData:
        {
            if(IS_EVENT_TYPE_OF(evTestSuccess_TestBasePkg_id))
                {
                    pushNullTransition();
                    rootState_subState = UpdateData;
                    rootState_active = UpdateData;
                    res = eventConsumed;
                }
            else if(IS_EVENT_TYPE_OF(evTestFailure_TestBasePkg_id))
                {
                    //#[ transition 3 
                    setState(ABORTED);
                    //#]
                    rootState_subState = terminationstate_4;
                    rootState_active = terminationstate_4;
                    res = eventConsumed;
                }

            break;
        }
        case UpdateData:
        {
            if(IS_EVENT_TYPE_OF(OMNullEventId))
                {
                    //## transition 5 
                    if(true == isNextFmAvailable())
                        {
                            popNullTransition();
                            //#[ transition 5 
                            populateNextFm();
                            //#]
                            rootState_subState = CalculateFiringData;
                            rootState_active = CalculateFiringData;
                            //#[ state ROOT.CalculateFiringData.(Entry) 
                            registerProcedure(new G(this, this, this, this));
                            //#]
                            res = eventConsumed;
                        }
                    else
                        {
                            //## transition 6 
                            if(false == isNextFmAvailable())
                                {
                                    popNullTransition();
                                    //#[ transition 6 
                                    setState(COMPLETED);
                                    //#]
                                    rootState_subState = terminationstate_4;
                                    rootState_active = terminationstate_4;
                                    res = eventConsumed;
                                }
                        }
                }

            break;
        }

        default:
            break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

I know this wont compile straight off but maybe it can gice some hints as to why it becomes errors.

> error: no matching function for call
>   to `F::F(A* const, A* const, A* const)
>   note: candidates are:
>   F::F(TestContextC*, D*, IOxfActive*)

Comment: This is not the real code isn't it? It is always better to copy paste the code from editor while asking questions. If you can't give the real code, make a test program with which you are able to reproduce the problem and post the code from there.

Comment: You code is not valid. Please post original code with the error.

Comment: Please post the actual code you are trying to compile.

Answer (score 3):

The problems in the code you posted are:

1. You use `C` before you declare it.
2. `B::doSomething` is trying to call a private `C` constructor.
3. `B::doSomething` is not missing the return type and argument list.
4. You're missing semicolons to end the class.

But once you fix those and get this code:

```
class A { };
class C
{
public:
    C(A* copy);
};
class B : public A {
    void doSomething() {
        C * c = new C(this);
    }
};
```

it compiles cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

With you code, I got the following errors.

```
:3: error: function definition does not declare parameters
:10: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
```

You error must come from somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 0):

make sure the constructor of C is public, so that it can be accessed from B.